# Cocoon, adding association to a specific model id rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

Im pretty new to Rails, and Im using Cocoon to do nested forms.
As of the documentation, link_to_add_association needs as third parameter, the association plural.

Having a tasks controller and a person and task model, I would like to know if instead of setting the association to 'people' for example, I could somehow get an specific person, like Person.find(id) when using link_to_add_association

So, what I want is not to add a blank input to set a new person in the form (as default from Cocoon), but to fill the input with the name of the person matching the ID

Comment: Suggest adding code you've tried so someone can help you out better

Comment: Yes, please show us how the models are associated.